# Python Networkx graph on x, y axis and having the edge attribute plot on the z axis matching the Networkx graph edges

Tags: python, graph, 3d, networkx, visualization

I have a 2D directional networkx graph representing underground pipeline networks, where the edge of the Networkx graph represent a single pipeline. I have set the attribute of each edge in the graph to be a NumPy array containing the following pressure distribution.

| Length (each pipe) | Pressure |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 10 | 90 |
| 20 | 80 |
| ... | ... |

I am trying to visualize all pipelines' internal pressure distribution within the same figure plot as the networkx graph. So, the ideal outcome is a 3D figure plot, where the x, y axis is the Networkx graph, and the z axis on each of the edge plotted in the x, y axis is the internal pressure distribution.

I have hand draw the figure with what I have in mind.

[image]

The following code is an example of my network graph with an edge attribute being a 2d NumPy array.

If there is a way to animate such drawing with changing pressure distribution will be even better.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Sections = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
Sources = np.array(["A", "B", "B", "D", "E"])
Targets = np.array(["B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])
Sections_L = np.array([250, 250, 100, 250, 250])
Sections_a = np.full(len(Sections), 1000)
Sections_D = np.array([0.173, 0.173, 0.1, 0.173, 0.173])
Sections_f = np.array([0.047, 0.047, 0.057, 0.047, 0.047])
Sections_U = np.array([0.85, 0.85, 2.55, 0.85, 0.85])
Sections_A = (np.pi * Sections_D ** 2) / 4
Sections_Q0 = Sections_A * Sections_U
Sections_S = np.zeros(len(Sections))
Data = np.column_stack(
    (Sections_L, Sections_D, Sections_A, Sections_a, Sections_f, Sections_U, Sections_Q0, Sections_S, Sources,
     Targets))
PipePD = pd.DataFrame(data=Data, index=Sections,
                      columns=["L", "D", "A", "a", "f", "U", "Q0", "isSource", "sources", "targets"])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(PipePD, source="sources", target="targets", edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

for edge in G.edges:
    length = int(G.edges[edge]["L"])
    lengthDist = range(0, length, 1)
    dist = np.random.uniform (0,10, len(lengthDist))
    PressureDist = np.column_stack((lengthDist, dist))
    G.edges[edge]["PressureDist"] = PressureDist


# plt.figure(1)
# edge_labels = {i[0:2]: '{}m'.format(i[2]['L']) for i in G.edges(data=True)}
# pos = nx.spring_layout(G, weight="L")
# nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
# nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels)
# plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would draw the network in 2D and use color to denote pressure.
However, you absolutely can use the z-axis instead. Networkx doesn't support custom edge paths, so you have to compute and draw them yourself.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Sections = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
Sources = np.array(["A", "B", "B", "D", "E"])
Targets = np.array(["B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])
Sections_L = np.array([250, 250, 100, 250, 250])
Sections_a = np.full(len(Sections), 1000)
Sections_D = np.array([0.173, 0.173, 0.1, 0.173, 0.173])
Sections_f = np.array([0.047, 0.047, 0.057, 0.047, 0.047])
Sections_U = np.array([0.85, 0.85, 2.55, 0.85, 0.85])
Sections_A = (np.pi * Sections_D ** 2) / 4
Sections_Q0 = Sections_A * Sections_U
Sections_S = np.zeros(len(Sections))
# This casts everything to strings!
# Data = np.column_stack(
#     (Sections_L, Sections_D, Sections_A, Sections_a, Sections_f, Sections_U, Sections_Q0, Sections_S, Sources,
#      Targets))
# Create a data dictionary instead:
data = (Sections_L, Sections_D, Sections_A, Sections_a, Sections_f, Sections_U, Sections_Q0, Sections_S, Sources, Targets)
columns = ["L", "D", "A", "a", "f", "U", "Q0", "isSource", "sources", "targets"]
PipePD = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(zip(columns, data)), index=Sections)
PipePD['L_inverse'] = 1. / PipePD['L']

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(PipePD, source="sources", target="targets", edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

for edge in G.edges:
    length = int(G.edges[edge]["L"])
    length_along_edge = range(0, length, 1)
    pressure = np.random.uniform(0,10, len(length_along_edge))
    # Smooth if you want to:
    # from statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess import lowess
    # length_along_edge, pressure = lowess(pressure, length_along_edge, 0.1).T
    G.edges[edge]["PressureDist"] = np.column_stack((length_along_edge, pressure))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, weight='L_inverse') # edges with high weight are short; you want long edges to be long (presumably)
edge_to_line = dict()
for (source, target) in G.edges:
    delta = pos[target] - pos[source]
    data = G.get_edge_data(source, target)
    total_length = data['L']
    length_along_edge, z = data['PressureDist'].T
    xy = (length_along_edge / total_length)[:,np.newaxis] * delta[np.newaxis,:] + pos[source]
    x, y = xy.T
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, z)
    edge_to_line[(source, target)] = line # save reference for easy access in animation
plt.show()
```

To animate the plot, you can manipulate the x, y, z coordinates of each line in your `update` function using the `set_data_3d` line method.

Code not tested:

```
frame_data = ... # e.g. a list of dictionaries, one for each frame, mapping edges to z values
def update(frame_index):
    artists_to_update = []
    for edge, z in frame_data[frame_index].items():
        line = edge_to_line[edge]
        x, y, _ = line.get_data_3d()
        line.set_data_3d(x, y, z)
        artists_to_update.append(line)
    return artists_to_update

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(len(frame_data)))
```

Comment: Thank you !!! The reason why i choose to plot such plot in 3D is that my pressure distribution can vary significantly within the same pipe. If I decide to use 2D network plot with colors, it will likely to render small changes in pressure unnoticable when i have a gaint spike at one end.

Comment: Another question to the 3D plot is that is there a way to make this plot interactable? For example that i can drag the network nodes around to make the pressure distribution plot of a particular edge more readable.

Comment: Unlike in 2D, the position of the cursor is ambiguous in a 3D plot w.r.t. x, y, z. So I don't think that is possible.